# Http communication with C application

Tags: apache-flex, sockets, air, flex3

I have a C program and that runs a web server. I have a Air Application and I want to communicate with that web server using Air Application. I create a socket object and do the following.

```
public function httpTest():void
    {      
      sock.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, onConnect);
      sock.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, onDataRecv);
      sock.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onError);
      try
      {
        trace("Connecting...");
        sock.connect("127.0.0.1", 9800);            
        sock.writeMultiByte("GET /Connection?data=version", "us-ascii");
        sock.flush();
      }
      catch(err:Error)
      {
        trace(err.message);
      }
    }

    public function onConnect(event:Event):void
    {
      trace("onConnect +");
    }

    public function onDataRecv(event:ProgressEvent):void
    {
      trace("onDataRecv +");
    }

    public function onError(event:Event):void
    {
      trace("onError +");
    }
```

socket connects successfully and its connection event is fired. but when I try to request the connection url nothing is received on server side. am I missing something. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what "request the connection URL" means in this contenxt; nor what piece of your code is doing that.

Comment: I connect at local host. it is a success. but when I try to request something else. it does not work. when I try the same URL from web browser it work fine. like  "http://127.0.0.1:9800/Connection?data=version"

Comment: What does "Does not work" mean.  Can you please quantify?  Do you get runtime errors?  Or compile time errors?  Or something else?  Does the onError method execute?  If so; what are the details?

Comment: onError does not execute. the string I write on socket simply does not get received on server side. But when I connect the socket onConnect executes. there is no compile time time or runtime time. no exception either. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a mistake. I did not add HTTP version and string terminator in the Get String. Thats why I did not receive any print on server side. Because the request was invalid. I posted the working code. Thanks for help.

```
public function httpTest():void
    {      
      sock.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, onConnect);
      sock.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, onDataRecv);
      sock.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onError);
      try
      {
        trace("Connecting...");
        sock.connect("127.0.0.1", 9800);            
        sock.writeMultiByte("GET /Connection?data=version HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n", "us-ascii");
        sock.flush();
      }
      catch(err:Error)
      {
        trace(err.message);
      }
    }

    public function onConnect(event:Event):void
    {
      trace("onConnect +");
    }

    public function onDataRecv(event:ProgressEvent):void
    {
      trace("onDataRecv +");
    }

    public function onError(event:Event):void
    {
      trace("onError +");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Like just about everything to do with networking in Flex, `socket.connect` is asynchronous and non-blocking, meaning that just because `sock.connect` has returned without error it doesn't mean the socket is actually ready for use yet.   I suspect that if you put `trace(sock.connected)` in your original code after your call to `writeMultiByte` it will print `false`.

You will need to delay your `sock.writeMultiByte` call until the connection is ready, which isn't until your `onConnect` handler fires.  Try:

```
try
{
    trace("Connecting...");
    sock.connect("127.0.0.1", 9800);            
}
catch(err:Error)
{
    trace(err.message);
}
...
public function onConnect(event:Event):void
{
  trace("onConnect +");
  sock.writeMultiByte("GET /Connection?data=version", "us-ascii");
  sock.flush();
}
```

Comment: Its quit helpful but I was making mistake somewhere else. when I use the Get method, at the end of the string I did not use "\r\n\r\n" and HTTP version. I post the working code. Thanks everyone for your help.